# npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-38-generic

Tags: node.js, npm

I got this problem after install nodejs and npm in my Ubuntu 18.04 and I tried to start it with npm start I get this error :

> npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
>   npm ERR! node v8.10.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
>   npm ERR! path /home/crispy/package.json
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/crispy/package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/crispy/package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/crispy/npm-debug.log

I am a newbie please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please show how your project is structured and in what route you're trying to run the commands. Also include the commands that you used

Comment: you mean show you the directory